# Can I get a typed Options object from full appsettings.json?

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core-3.1

From the ASP.NET Core documentation it looks like I can only bind a named subdivision of configuration to a typed object using `IConfiguration::Bind<T>()` or `IConfiguration::Get<T>()`.

I wonder if there is a way to have the whole `appsettings.json` file copied from the root into a typed object.

Is this possible?

If it is, do I need to provide all configuration settings as public properties in my typed object or can I omit some of them and the binder will automatically skip items I don't provide in my typed object? (I imagine that other providers add loads of configuration settings which I wouldn't want to add to my `Options` object.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`IConfigurationRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationroot?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), which represents the root of the configuration and include all sections of your `appsettings.json`, is also an [`IConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) so you can use it in places where you would use an `IConfiguration` to configure things.

That means that you could call `Bind()` on the configuration root to bind it fully to an object, or that you could use the [`services.Configure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method to configure an options type with the full configuration root:

```
services.Configure<AllOptions>(Configuration);
```

> If it is, do I need to provide all configuration settings as public properties in my typed object or can I omit some of them and the binder will automatically skip items I don't provide in my typed object?

During bind, the binder will skip values that it cannot bind to the target object. So yes, the configuration object can include more values than the target type supports.